# Mapear colunas de tabelas separadas em um único objeto e vice-versa

Tags: java, sql, classes, orm

> Situação 1

Tenho as seguintes tabelas, bem simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui].......................
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho as seguintes classes:

**Cliente:**

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7402770378598465859L;

    private Short id;
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="data_nascimento")
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;

    private Contato contato;

    //Constructor
    // get e sets
}
```

**Contato:**

```
@Entity
public class Contato implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5040500676803061821L;

    private String telefone;
    private String celular;

    //Constructor
    // get e sets
}
```

**Funcionário:**

```
@Entity
public class Funcionario implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5718684144972644433L;

    private Short id;
    private String nome;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private boolean ativo;
    private Contato contato;

    //Constructor
    // get e sets
}
```

> Situação 2

Tenho as seguintes tabelas, bem simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E tenho as seguintes classes:

**Cliente:**

```
@Entity
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7402770378598465859L;

    private Short id;
    private String nome;

    @Column(name = "data_nascimento")
    private LocalDate dataNascimento;

    private String telefone;
    private String celular;

    // Constructor
    // get e sets
}
```

**Funcionário:**

```
@Entity
public class Funcionario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5718684144972644433L;

    private Short id;    
    private String nome;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private boolean ativo;
    private String telefone;
    private String celular;

    // Constructor
    // get e sets
}
```

> Questões

1 - Na "Situação 1", temos 2 tabelas e 3 classes, na qual as propriedades *telefone* e *celular* da classe *Contato* são representados como colunas nas tabelas *Funcionário* e *Cliente* no banco de dados, como é feito o mapeamento desta situação utilizando o JPA?

2 - Na "Situação 2", temos 3 tabelas e 2 classes, na qual as colunas da tabela "Contato" do banco de dados são representadas na aplicação como propriedades das classes *Funcionário* e *Cliente*, como faço o mapeamento utilizando o JPA nesta situação?

3 - Na classe Cliente temos a propriedade *dataNascimento* que armazena um objeto do tipo `java.time.LocalDate`. A **JPA**(2.1) e/ou **Hibernate**(4.3.5.Final) fornece alguma anotação ou algum outro meio para o mapeamento deste objeto? Se não, há alguma outra alternativa senão voltar a usar o `java.util.Date`?

4 - Esta é uma questão de curiosidade sobre SQL, o atributo do tipo *BIT* atualmente tem alguma diferença do TINYINT(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo a situação 1 e 2:

O que você precisa para resolver a situação 1 está na situação 2 e vice-versa, ou seja, na situação 1 você tem 2 tabelas e o código da situação 2 está anotado para 2 entidades.
Tem também a possibilidade, na situação 1, de criar a classe Contato sem está anotada para o JPA e fazer com que as outras herdem dela. Na situação 2, os atributos pertencem a tabela de Contatos, logo não podem ser anotados em outras entidades. Nesse caso faça o seguinte (solução alternativa para a situação 2):

1. Crie a entidade Contato;
2. Substitua os atributos telefone e celular das classes por uma variável do tipo Contato;
3. Faça a anotação usando @OneToOne como está no relacionamento.

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Contato implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -5040500676803061821L;

       private String telefone;
       private String celular;

       //Constructor
       // get e sets
   }

   @Entity
   public class Cliente implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 7402770378598465859L;

       private Short id;
       private String nome;

       @Column(name="data_nascimento")
       @Temporal(DATE)
       private Calendar dataNascimento;

       @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       private Contato contato;

       //Constructor
       // get e sets
   }

   @Entity
   public class Funcionario implements Serializable{

       private static final long serialVersionUID = -5718684144972644433L;

       private Short id;
       private String nome;
       private String rg;
       private String cpf;
       private boolean ativo;

       @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
       private Contato contato;

       //Constructor
       // get e sets
   }
   ```

Respondendo o 3, veja que alterei o tipo da data de nascimento para Calendar e coloquei a anotação @Temporal.

Sobre o BIT em relação ao TINYINT(1) é que o BIT por padrão em alguns bancos de dados é reconhecido como campo do tipo booleano, ou seja, ele sempre aceitará 0 ou 1 ou FALSE ou TRUE. Já o TINYINT armazena valores inteiros maiores que 1 ou menores que 0, depende de como foi definido e, mesmo definindo ele assim TINYINT(1) não muda o seu comportamento. Portanto, se vai trabalhar com valores booleanos, use o BIT.

Observação: Se o relacionamento for 1 pra 1, remova a tabela Contato da base de dados e coloque os atributos na Cliente e Funcionário. Facilitará seu lado e evita o uso excessivo de Join. :D

Atualizado:

Caso queira manter a tabela separada e usar seus atributos nas entidades pode usar a anotação @Embeddable.

[Oracle Javadoc Embeddable](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html)

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por me responder. A pergunta que fiz é porque eu criei primeiramente as classes Cliente e Funcionário, no entanto, estas duas classes possuíam muitos atributos semelhantes além de celular e telefone (só coloquei esses dois atributos para simplificar), então criei primeiramente a classe Contato, colocando os atributos semelhantes sobre **contato** nesta classe para mitigar a redundância de atributos, tinha criado a classe Endereço, que contém também atributos redundantes das classes Funcionário e Cliente, mas não coloquei na pergunta para simplificá-la.

Comment: Como na sua observação, é desnecessário criar uma tabela extra para Contatos sendo que as associações para este são 1-1, que poderia como você mesmo disse, ocorrer perca de performance. Mas no meu caso **real**, eu tenho ainda a classe Endereço, que possui 7 atributos redundantes das classes Cliente, Funcionário e **Pedido** (endereço para onde enviar o pedido) reunidos nela. Na sua opinião, neste meu cenário, você acha melhor eu mitigar a redundância e criar tabelas como Contato e Endereço(relacionamentos para estas classes são 1-1), ou deixar as tabelas com muitos atributos redundantes?

Comment: Cara, a vantagem de não criar uma tabela de Contato e Endereço e não mapiar-las é que a JPA não vai fazer os Joins automáticos, ou seja, aumenta a performance do Framework. Em contra-partida, você vai ter muitos atributos repetidos em suas entidades. Não sei o que recomendar a você, pois ambas tem suas vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Uma coisa que esqueci de citar, no caso da data, você mudou para _Calendar_ o que não está errado, mas como li algumas coisas sobre a biblioteca `java.time` do Java 8 e por este possuir uma série de vantagens eu queria utilizá-la no meu projeto e queria saber se havia uma anotação que eu pudesse usar para mapear o `java.time.LocalDate`, e não os `java.util.Date` ou `java.util.Calendar` das versões anteriores do Java.

Comment: Vou ser sincero, ainda não trabalho com Java 8 mas, se for utilizar-lo, dizem que o Joda veio para ficar mas não tenho conhecimento da mesma. Outra coisa, falando sobre sua entidade separada, dê uma olhada na anotação @Embeddable e como trabalhar com ela.

Comment: Cara, era algo assim que estava procurando, a anotação @Embeddable torna possível que eu separe as colunas em objetos distintos, como a tabela Cliente, e separar esta em classe Cliente e classe Endereço, mantendo a coesão de que classe Endereço é intrínseco a classe Cliente.